# Raspberry pi 400: no sound through HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, pi-400

I've got a karaoke system with an hdmi input and an hdmi output. It works perfectly when connecting the input to a video player or a computer, but when connected to my pi, the image go through HDMI, but the sound not.

My raspebbery is a pi 400, the sound works when connected directly to a TV, but not when using the karaoke. I tried versions bullseye 32 bits and bookworm 32 bits, with no luck.
How can I force the raspberry to output the audio to the hdmi?
I tried changing `/boot/config.txt`, adding `hdmi_drive=2`, then `hdmi_group=1` or `hdmi_group=4`.
Nothing works, the pi is silent, clicking in the audio icon in the menu bar doesn't give any output option

Comment: Not familiar w/ RPi 400, *BUT* you may want to try `cec-utils`. There's a package available through `apt`, and [here's an article on it](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberrypi-hdmi-cec/). Let us know how it works out - there seems to be an epidemic of sound issues lately & others will be interested.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I had no luck with it. cec-utils just sees `device #1: Recorder 1` which seems to be the pi itself, when connected to the karaoke, and even when I connect it directly to the TV